# Help new users understand why their post was downvoted

Tags: feature-request, downvotes, downvote-reason

I am proposing a feature that would allow new users to understand why their question was downvoted. The system should show the owner of a post that has eg. a score of < -3 or a score of < 0 and at least one pending close vote/flag a message like this:

> **Attention!** Please clarify your post!
>
> Some users downvoted your post because it is not clear enough. This are a few tips how to improve your post.
>
> - Questions asking us to debug code require a [MCVE](/help/mcve) and the error message.
> - Please **always** say what you have already accomplished.
> - Do not add try to improve your question by adding code or other information in an answer or a comment. **Instead edit your questions**
> - Read [How to ask?](/help/how-to-ask) again
>
> If you do not follow these guidelines your post is probably not answered, [closed](/help/closed-questions) and/or deleted.

It should look like this (with red FHC):
[image: Example Oh-Noh-Post-was-downvoted-message]

Comment: That's an impressive mockup. Still, read [Why isn't commenting mandatory on downvotes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-commenting-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggesting-such-s?rq=1).

Comment: Maybe this is just a minor point, but there certainly are reasons to downvote other than lack of clarity.

Comment: The condition score < -3 is just an example condition. You could also take score < 0 and open close votes/flags or anything else that suites you best

Comment: MEE, better add something like "... for new (< 5 days/months/years) and/or low reputation (< 10) users" before the on average high-rep Meta crowd closes this down.

Comment: @JoshCaswell This isn't proposing any sort of mandatory comments when downvoting.

Comment: @usr2564301 This was what I implied with *new users*

Comment: @usr2564301 If we determined that a message like this was useful (see my answers for numerous problems with the current message) why wouldn't we want older users or users with more rep to see it?

Comment: @Servy: that's a pretty good idea. Last week I had someone with (I believe) about 4K rep using Unicode equivalent characters to replace  `problm` in a title to slightly obfuscated `problem`. I guess at times higher rep users need reminding of the basic rules as well.

Comment: Being unuseful and/or off-topic are other common reasons to down vote. That should be taken into account. It should also only say that these are likely reasons for the down votes since sometimes it happens for other reasons.

Comment: @BSMP It should be possible for the system to find out what kind of close votes are pending. Then you may show this message only for unclear, too broad, debugging-off-topic ("why isn't this code working?")

Comment: @MEE We don't need a second banner for each close reason to repeat the close reason.  We already have the close reason banner.  Users that have those problems with their question are *already* getting a banner explaining that they have that problem with their question.

Comment: @Servy but this would help users before their question is closed. It would remind them, that they need to improve something or won't get answers (because of nobody understands their problem, closed or deleted)

Comment: @MEE If you want to show the close banner to the author before the question is closed, but when it has some number of votes, then propose *that*.  It's radically different from what you have currently suggested.  A post being downvoted doesn't mean it merits closure, and that a post merits closure doesn't mean it has been downvoted.

Comment: @Servy please note my edit: I am not proposing to show the close banner before the question is closed. I can totally understand that we should not show this message only for downvotes but showing this message could alert a user that they have to improve their question and prevent a (possible very long) repoen process

Comment: "I am not proposing to show the close banner before the question is closed." I know.  I'm saying that would actually be useful, if you think that the problem is that a user needs to be presented with the close reason before the question has finished being closed.  I'm saying that what you're actually suggesting, presenting a bunch of close reasons just because the question has been downvoted, is wrong, because the question won't necessary have those problems, because downvotes and close votes are independent of each other

Comment: @MEE You can't delete it as it's answered.  It doesn't meet any criteria for closure as far as I can see.  You're of course more than welcome to make a different question, based on what you've learned from this one.  If you want to stop responding to comments (presumably what you mean by abandon) on this one that's of course your prerogative, you're not obligated to interact beyond asking the question.

Comment: As @Servy proposed I posted a new feature-request for showing posts that they are in danger of being closed: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362087/help-new-users-why-their-post-was-downvoted-version-2

Comment: *I can totally understand that we should not show this message only for downvotes...* Maybe the OP should get a warning even if they've only gotten down votes. I'm personally not against that idea, I just think the wording should change.

Comment: Missing reason: [Tim lost his keys again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-downvoting-be-more-effectively-caught/215397#215397).

Comment: @BSMP The wording I give in the feature-proposal is just an idea/example. It has probably to be improved

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We don't want to tell people that their questions are lacking a reproducible example if their questions have problems other than a lack of a reproducible example.  If their question *is* lacking a reproducible example, it'll be closed for the appropriate close reason, providing a banner just like that with a (slightly better worded) warning saying something similar.

The same applies if the question is unclear, or otherwise lacking sufficient information for an answer.

If the user is posting information that should be in an edit in a comment or answer, then that wouldn't be the reason for downvotes, so telling them how to edit isn't really appropriate here.

Linking to the how to ask page is the only thing in there that would actually be merited, although I'm not sure how helpful it'd be.  The user has already been shown that page before they were allowed to ask the question, and they either read it and it didn't help, or they've already made the decision to not bother accepting the help that we can give them, but I'm not fundamentally opposed to that bit of info being presented again in a situation where it's likely that the author didn't read it and needs to, even if I don't expect it will actually change anything.

Comment: There is a whole category of bad questions where there is a code example in the question but it does nothing to help. For example, imagine a question like: "I am trying to build a new Facebook (just for fun guys!) and what I have so far is `int main(int argc, char** argv) { printf("Hello Facebok\n"); }` but it doesn't look like Facebook. What am I missing?" -- Even though that question has code in it, it is not remotely answerable, and telling the user to put more code in the question isn't going to make it more answerable.

Comment: @DanielPryden The close reason doesn't say, "put in more code", it says that the code doesn't reproduce the problem described, or that there isn't a good description of the problem.

Answer (score -23):

There is already a great tool to help users know why you downvoted... the comment that you left when you downvoted (you did do that, right?)

In addition to leaving a friendly comment welcoming them to the site and reminding them that image-only questions are difficult for us to deal with, you may also provide a link to (e.g.) [idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) for further explanation, and to give them some next steps to improve their question-asking skills.

Comment: _"the comment that you left when you downvoted (you did do that, right?)"_ -- no, I didn't. For one, many of the close reasons are self-explanatory...no comment is needed to explain, when simply having voted to close suffices. Second, even if a comment _could_ improve things, it often does not. Many of us have found that commenting is perceived as an invitation to the question author to debate the downvote, to berate the voter, or even to go on a down-voting spree (which may or may not be reversed). Indeed, I find that I usually either down-vote or comment, but very often not both.

Comment: I want to downvote you for this answer because leaving a comment is not required and is often not recommended, but that website you linked could be surprisingly useful. Without being unnecessarily rude or patronising it might help to add one of those links to a comment explaining a downvote. I'll bookmark it and if I see an appropriate situation I may use it.

Comment: @PeterDuniho absolutely. Voting to close is sufficient and a comment should not be needed. This is about downvotes.

Comment: @Clonkex and you_can_ downvote if you like. Votes are different on Meta and don't indicate whether a post is useful, could be improved, or those sort of things necessarily. Glad you found the link useful.

Comment: @NH. True. Have a free downvote, on the house :P

Comment: @Clonkex I was confused, if it's useful why do you want to downvote it? / SO had a meta question whether idownvotedbecau.se is good, and the answers are pretty negative.

Comment: @user202729 I'm downvoting it because I disagree with the post. NH. is implying we should always leave a comment when downvoting a post, but that's not the case. I found the link in the answer useful, but my feelings about the implied requirement to leave a comment when downvoting outweigh any usefulness I found in the link. Additionally, except for [meta.stackexchange.com](http://meta.stackexchange.com), votes on meta sites down give or take rep, so I have no qualms about downvoting a suggestion I simply don't agree with.

Comment: maybe you inferred that, but I won't actually say always. It all comes down to what is helpful, and I hope people will find comments, and /or that website, useful.

Comment: _"This is about downvotes"_ -- yes, but down-votes and close votes are often correlated. For example, a question that is too broad (close vote) is often also not useful (down vote). Other reasons a question may be poorly received and thus down-voted also show up in close votes as well.