# Help new users understand why their post was down-/closevoted - Version 2

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, close-reasons, new-users

I have recently proposed to show a message to new users warning about possible content problems ([here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/362082/4284627)).

In the comments-discussion @Servy proposed the alternate idea to show the post's author a warning that their post might be closed (eventually closed) for other close reasons than `duplicate`. This warning should look similiar to the close reasons and should give the user some advice what to do:

- improve the post and clarify why it should not be closed
- vote/flag to close the post themself

The message could look like this (probably with a different wording):

[image]

or with a bit less prominent background color:

[image]

Of course this could be implemented in a way that shows this message only for new users (< 5-10 rep, first question, ...).

Comment: I thought you always see close votes on your own questions?

Comment: @BDL This is not valid for users with 250 rep. They have only the option to flag their own posts.

Comment: @MEE, that's not what BDL are saying. That when you get close votes in one of your questions, you get a banner informing you of that. I know that when I posted a "possible duplicate" here on meta, I did get that banner.

Comment: @yivi but this banner is only for possible duplicates as I stated in the question (second paragraph, second line)

Comment: I thought a similar banner was shown for the other close reasons. I stand corrected.

Comment: @BDL Even users that have the 250 rep to cast close votes on their own question aren't necessarily going to understand that when they see `close (3)` that it means that there are three pending close votes, and that clicking on the "close" button would show them the existing votes and those reasons.  They may also not realize, even after clicking that link, that the numbers in a blue box represent the number of existing votes for those reasons.  That's asking a lot of people that aren't regularly closing other people's questions.

Comment: Not to be flippant, but there are already a number of ways new users are introduced and directed towards documentation that would assist them in posing good questions. Most of the time it is ignored (at least from what I see daily). I suspect that throwing more gas on the fire won't put it out if you know what I mean.

Comment: "is eventually closed" -> "might be closed".

Comment: @JacobH: this is for the users that just 'need ur answer' and click through dialogs, popups, and warning screens until they can finally post it. IMO it is not that different from the warnings we *all* have seen when auditing posts and suggested edits.

Comment: Sure, why not. Maybe this could also be public visible? That way some FGITW's realize, they should not give an answer (< 2k people)

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt I would disagree showing this to everybody as it is primarily to help the OP and is no official closed, on-hold state. Showing it to everybody would probably lead to confusion.

Comment: Questions are no longer closer, they are put "on hold", which means that the OP has a chance to improve the question before it gets truly closed (and perhaps eventually deleted).

Comment: This is similar to [Can we incorporate what idownvotedbecau.se is trying to do?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357702/can-we-incorporate-what-idownvotedbecau-se-is-trying-to-do)

Comment: I don't understand. Was the question closed or not? If it was closed then such a message is already shown. Was not yet closed? But downvoted? There could be several reasons, but most common are shown in tooltip of downvote button. Or you want to give user info "faster" before it's closed? Why? To solve what problem?

Comment: @Lundin Questions *do* still get closed.  The label says, "on hold" instead of "closed" for a few days so that authors of a post better understand that they're expected to fix their question, not abandon it, and that it's not final.  Even when the label changes to "closed" we *still* want to them to fix it, and they're still more than welcome to do so and have their question reopened.  Closure is *never* final; it merely lasts until the author fixes the problems with the question.

Comment: @Servy Yes, that's what I wrote.

Comment: @Lundin You said, "Questions are no longer close", which isn't true, and said, "has a chance to improve the question before it gets truly closed" implying that they can't improve the question once it is closed, which also isn't true.  The only difference between "on hold" and "closed" is the text in the label.  There's no reason to treat them like different things.  Finally you end with, "(and perhaps eventually deleted)" yet a question can be deleted when it's "on hold" too; there's nothing about the label change that has anything to do with deletion, despite your indication to the contrary.

Comment: @Dukeling I added a new screenshot using `might be closed` and another less prominent grayer version

Comment: Next, let's add color changes, flashing lights, and a siren as each close vote is added, to make sure that they know they are *really* getting close to closing...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan While I understand your concern, this isn't actually drawing attention to existing information, it is presenting users with information *which they currently can't see at all*. It could be less prominent than this, e.g. the details could be hidden behind a "show more" link, but I believe right now, a question can sit for days with 4 close votes but no comments, and the person who asked the question will get no feedback on what to improve until a 5th vote comes in.

Comment: @IMSoP I would be interested to see how often such a scenario occurs; namely, that people are left with "no feedback on what to improve". In my experience, there are many people who are more than willing to comment when they see something wrong on the internet... Perhaps such information would also drive whether the costs outweigh the benefits of such a feature.

Answer (score 5):

More times than not, by the time the warning can actually be seen by the OP, the decisive action on the question has been taken and the OP is none the wiser as to *why* it happened.

Put another way, even if we did show a message explaining why their question was closed or downvoted, it's highly unlikely that the OP would see it in enough time to understand the reason *and* fix their question before it was closed.

I suppose you can count this as a view against the message dialog.  For development effort, it does little to actively change or address the status quo.

Comment: So you're asserting that it's extremely like that a question would be seen by the question author after the first close vote but before the 5th?  That...doesn't seem unlikely at all.  In fact, that's why this is already done for duplicate questions.  And of course you can just look at the close vote queue, which is just full of questions with pending close votes that aren't closed.  And of course before questions aged out of that queue as aggressively it consistently had many hundreds of thousands of questions sitting in there for months.

Comment: @Servy:  I'm contending that there isn't anything an OP can do in situations where their question gets heavily downvoted, and there's nothing they can do to realistically "fix" it (e.g. someone asking a question about their personal networking setup, while on-topic elsewhere, isn't here, would incur lots of downvotes and be powerless to change anything about their question to stop the flood of downvotes).  I'm not a fan of messages that action can't be taken from, and this feels like one of them.

Comment: Sure *some* close worthy questions can't be fixed, but plenty can.  Most don't actually *get* fixed, but that's just because the OP doesn't try, not because it's not possible.  In a very sizeable percentage of cases the message *is* actionable.  It's also time sensitive; the faster the OP fixes the problem(s) with their question, the better.

Comment: @Servy: I suppose you've walked into my point.  The message isn't likely to change anything towards OPs actually fixing their bad questions, or give them any guidance to prevent it in the future.  The close message conveys the same message without the same limbo-like state that a message like this would put the question in. I suppose I could change my stance if I believed that the message was slightly more purposeful than hand waving.

Comment: So because some people would ignore the useful message that has important information for them that they *really* need to act on, and that they can act on, we shouldn't show it to *anyone*, even the people who would actually act on it?  So why tell anyone anything ever?  Why have any close reason at all if you don't think showing anyone any message ever is worthwhile because every single one of them doesn't act on it?

Answer (score -2):

Change **might be closed** to read **has been flagged by members of the community for not meeting the minimum quality standards and risks being put on hold before you can get answers for the following reasons:**

Then list all the reasons for the various votes.

#### Why would you want it to be LESS prominent?

I think it should be more so and any current answers, which in most cases are not really answers, usually comments or guesses in the answer boxes be hidden until they take some action by acknowledging the warning.

Comment: The issue in the wording change is that I stopped reading after it felt like the members of the community had an issue with *me* and not my question. It's more straightforward and evocative to just say **might be closed**.

Comment: @Pureferret - well that is you, anyone who upvotes your comment, projecting ...

Comment: What do you mean by "projecting" exactly?

Comment: [Projection/Projecting](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Projection). - if means you are ascribing attributes/motives/intent to someone else that are not there because that is what **you** think, not because there is any empirical evidence of such. It ascribe something that specifically targets the question to be a personal attack qualifies this 100% as projecting.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Although my comment was more expressing a hypothetical reaction, just because projecting misconstrues your intent, it doesn't stop people from doing it.

Comment: You miss the point, **you are accusing someone of doing something they did not do, in public, with absolutely no proof**. That is the problem, you are accusing me of malicious intent and justifying it with *"well some people do it so it is a valid argument you are doing it now as well"* Based on your unfounded attempts at Public Shaming, You really need to read up on the [Be Nice!](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) policy, because unfounded accusations and attempts at public shaming fall directly afoul of just that.